# Bad Base64 encoding error while creating SSH key in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, encryption

Does anyone see this error while uploading a public PGP key to create SSH key for SFMC SFTP?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [official documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_key_create_ssh_for_ftp.htm&type=5) on this is really confusing, in my opinion.  [Here's](https://sprignaturemoves.com/ssh-keys-for-sftp-in-sfmc/) what you need to make it work for both scenarios:

### SFMC pushing files to third-party SFTP via SSH

#### SFMC

**Private SSH Key**

**Specifications**

- RSA
- 2048-bit
- OpenSSH format
- Can be created with or without passphrase using with [ssh-keygen](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/keygen) or [puttygen](https://www.puttygen.com/)

**Installation**

- SSH option must be enabled by SF Support
- Upload key file as SSH type in `Setup > Admin > Data Management > Key Management`

#### Third Party

**Public SSH Key**

**Specifications**

- See Private Key specifications

**Installation**

- Specific to third-party key management system

### Third-party pushing files to SFMC SFTP via SSH

#### SFMC

**Public SSH Key**

**Specifications**

- See Private Key specifications

**Installation**

- Create a new SFTP Account for connection in `Setup > Admin > Data Management > FTP Accounts`
- SSH option must be enabled by SF Support
- Upload key file as SSH type in `Setup > Admin > Data Management > Key Management`

#### Third-party

**Private SSH Key**

**Specifications**

- RSA
- 4096-bit
- PEM format only
- With or without a passphrase
- Can be created with [ssh-keygen](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/keygen) or [puttygen](https://www.puttygen.com/)

**Installation**

- Specific to third-party key management system

Comment: Thanks for reply @Adam. 3rd party key i got from customer is public PGP file but in TXT file format. should i request new file in RSA,2048-bit and OpenSSH format ?

Comment: Yes, I would.  The above is what SFMC supports.